Google oauth2 -> get UserInfo doesn't return the new updated profile
Because i cannot contact to google so i have to write it here. I hope google guys can read it.
How to reproduce:
Step 1: Login with an account google then goto https://myaccount.google.com/profile/name and change your name.
Step 2:
In Client use script to handle Login for your google account and get the login code;
Currently i'm using https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference to handle the login in web.
const client = window.google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
            client_id: config.google.clientId,
            scope: 'openid email profile',
            select_account: true,
            include_granted_scopes: false,
            enable_granular_consent: false,
            ux_mode: 'popup',
            callback: res => {
              if (!res.code) {
                console.info(res);
                return;
              }
              // send the res.code to server to continue login
            },
            error_callback: err => {
              // err.type
              // popup_failed_to_open The popup window is failed to open.
              // popup_closed The popup window is closed before an OAuth response is returned.
              // unknown Placeholder for other errors.
              console.info('Google Login Error', err);
              redirectLogin();
            },
          });

          client.requestCode();

Step3:
Server handle the code to get access token and request the userinfo.
const tokens = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(res);
    });
  });

  oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

  const oauth2 = google.oauth2('v2');
  const userInfo = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    oauth2.userinfo.get({ auth: oauth2Client }, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(res.data);
    });
  });

The userInfo doesn't include the updated your profile name

Expectation:
The userInfo should be returned with the updated name.

even i have tried with API https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo. it returns the old profile.

go though the people api
